# How best create views for temporal data in couchbase

Tags: couchbase

I am interested in doing a website based on news, review articles etc.

Some key information i need to check is that the articles is in a valid time range i.e. between its start date and stop date to run on the site and its online.

How can i write a view for that? Ideally you would want a view like

```
var now = new Date();
if(doc.online && (doc.startDate <= now && now <= doc.stopDate))
   emit(doc.headline,null);
```

but that wont work if i understand views correctly i.e. the only update on doc insert/update
Do i really want to do a compound key that has the start and stop date in them so i can do range type queries and also have to deal with other complexities e.g. the type of article e.g. news, tagging of article etc.

Thanks

Comment: When you say temporal you mean the data/article will cease to be available? And you will make articles that will have to be published at a certain time automatically? Your question is quite broad and could need a few different approaches dependent on what you want, provide a bit more detail then we'll try again :)

Comment: The article is only valid to display on the website between the start and stop date and if online=true. So i would only want it in the view if meets these conditions. So the above code would work but only for that instance when it is indexed as opposed to at any time in the future. I could use a ttl to retire it i suppose, that would deal with the stopdate though if i wanted to use CB to find articles  that are not online then the article wouldnt be in CB at all.